# Why does my Angular app not display a websocket image feed unless I resize the window?

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket

Sorry its my first time and new in angular but i cant solve this with the questions asked before

I have a websocket connection where it sends image base64 sting every second from node backend to work like a camera feed. and in frontend angular i have a service that connects to websocket.

```js
export class CameraWebsocketService {
  imageData: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  conn;
  // private socket$ = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.5.100:8201/feed');

  openSocket() {
    this.conn = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.5.100:8201/feed');

    this.conn.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log('Opened live feed socket');
    };

    this.conn.onmessage = (event) => {
      this.imageData.next('data:image/jpg;base64,' + event.data);
    };
  }
}
```

when i try to access the image from a component

```js
export class CameraViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private ws: CameraWebsocketService
  ) {}

  apple = this.ws.imageData;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ws.openSocket();
  }
}
```

and in component.html
`<img [src]="apple | async" alt="" />`

it doesnot display unless i resize the window.
i have inspected the source code and can see img tag src updating but its not doing anything.

I have tried using changedetectorref and zone like some answers in other questions but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: try filling the `apple` value inside `ngOnInit`, that's where you are supposed to handle all the component logic initialization

Comment: @Andres2142 its still the same. Did you mean
`ngOnInit(){ this.apple = this.ws.imageData;}`
if yeah it didnt do anything

edit: i did `this.ws.imageData.subscribe((data)=>{this.apple = data})`
and remove async pipe from component.html. still the same

Comment: try using `imageData = BehaviorSubject<string>(' ')` on your service instead of a `Subject`.

Comment: Also, provide in your service a function to get the subject as an `Observable`, like: `getWS(): Observable<string> { return this.ws.asObservable()  }`. The `ws` on your service should be a `private` field

Comment: @Andres2142 Thankyou for your time but still the same. Works if i resize the screen.

Comment: What if you call `openSocket()` within the `service` constructor, not in the component? Shouldn't the service be in charge of initializing the socket? rather than the component?

Comment: Also, try `pipe`ing the subject with `tap` and see what is the content when is about to do a `next`, like `this.ws.pipe(tap(x => console.log('x: ', x))).next(...)`

Comment: @Andres2142 changed service to  Observable and ws connects inside service as well but it still acts the same as before. Screen shows blank but inspect element shows src with base64 data and works evevrytime i resize my window. :(